# Are there any particular characters or sequences that should never be put in an image description?

Tags: support, images, alt-text

Answer(s) to [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/303080) (found in [metaFAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080)) explain several reasons why we should

> replace the default "enter image description here" with something meaningful.

Are there any particular characters or sequences that should never be put in an image description? Things that might break the page or result in undesirable or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292415/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285366/282094

Answer (score 12):

> result in undesirable or unexpected behavior?

Consider the idea is screen readers should be able to read it, and it should describe the image. You're probably better off not using many of these

- Emoji
- 
- ssǝuıןןıs ɹǝɥʇo ɹO
- Of course Zalgo text, a thing so horrible I'm hiding it under a spoiler tag so it doesn't break weaker minds, or at least hide the rest of the abominations I've trotted out

  > L̷̹̈͗́̎̒̉̽ë̷̢̤͕̙̬͕͎̘̳̹̳́̈́͊̌̂́̕̚̕ͅţ̷̧̢̛͇͉͖͎̥͔̫̞̠͉̗͋̃̑̍s̵̳̹̪͓͈̹̟̏͗͛̓͘ ̵̟̮͍̼̜̦̝̩̎̂̄ņ̶̝̖̣̮͍̱̫͍͑̉ǒ̵̞͖̏̚ṭ̶̨͕̄̍͊͌̈͐̋̈́̕ ̸̖̯͉̠͎̜̙͉͙̤͕̮̭͇̣̈́̔̽̽f̷̨͚̙̯̱̮͓̙̩͍͚̺͑̈́̿̉͆͜ợ̸̢̢̢̛͙̗͙͍̹̝̖̳̬̗̒̔́̌̎̈́́͐̆́͘̚͜r̵̨̘̳̺̖̝̥̮͇̙̯̜̊̅̋͐̚͜͝ͅg̵̹̦̰̗̫͌͑̏̊̾̎̓̆͆̑̏̈̚͠͠͝ȩ̷̛̖̹̖̬̳̹̺̮͈̜̩̯̹̈͂̃͌̍̊̊̽́͂̾̿̈́̚͝͠ͅt̷̛͉̺̺̜̙͇͋͆͂̌̈̑̌̂̄͂͝ ̴̭̏̋̉̂̂̀͊̈́̎̀̿͂͐͒̾̚͝t̸̨̨͖̹̰͇̭̖̜͕͖̘̘͍̭͇͔̍̏̀̂̚h̸̨̞̫̼̯͈̙̪͇̟͍̼̩̘͋͗́̉̋̅̄̒͑͗̇̋͘͠ͅͅę̷̡̪̼͔͔̪̥̜͕̫̙̝̮̼̺̀̓͊̄̋͝ ̶̡̡̭͇͉͔̝͍̻͇̩͈̬̼͛͊͛̒͊̋͂̌̈́̅͋̉̄͐͐̇͜͝ͅh̸̡̡̛̛̙̖̳̜̹̼̙̲̽͊ō̶̠̐̊́̏͗̅̿́r̶̨̳̩͕͗r̷̰̎͗̐̏̑̑̈́̂̔͘ơ̶̡̨̛̬͍̟̻̖͕͚̦̭͖̜̲̍̏̂̊̒̊́́̆̊̅̄́̏̚ṙ̶̢̩̥̝̟̪͓͈̱̥͂ͅş̸̰̟̟͇͇͗̓̋̍͋ ̷̣̗̯̝̘̘̼̐̅̉͛̂͑̕͜o̴̡̨̗̺̺̣͇͔̼̰̮̫̐̈́̓̋̽̎́f̸̨͎̬̲̹̝͓͔̮̪͎̭̿́̐̆̍͆̕ ̴̛̺͚̗̭̼̳̦̘͍͈̘̗̫̠͔̞̀͆͋̓̉͌͒͘̚͝͠ş̸̭̻̰͈͇̮̳͈͓͕̙̅̉̓̋̓̂̀̆͘͘͝ẗ̸̛͎̣̼̻͖͙͓̥͔̤͕̖͖̿̀͆͐̋̍͌͜a̵͇̍̀c̵̰͎̪̼͚͇̲͍̞͖͛̈́́̌̀͆k̷̡̢̛͔̤̯͇̫͎̤̦̞̙̦̦̙̰ͅȅ̸̝̝̪͙͓̗͈̼̟̟͖̺̎̀̈d̴͙͐̀̒̉̅͗̔͂̾͑͐̀̋̆̕̕ ̴͕̠̟͉̩̥̦̭͔̓́̄̿͗͋̎͌̄͋͗̾̀d̷̛̲̘͔̰̖̼͙̺̳͌̌i̸̡͍͉̯͗̔a̴̭̯̲̬̿̿̂̊͒̌̈̑͠c̶̡̢̥̳͉̘̻̋r̵̘͕̻̮̤̱͑̊̏̎̒͊̌͒̀̉͝i̶̛̯͙̹̊͛̒̂͆͛̽̇̋͂̈́̿͋́̒̒t̶̢̖͇͕̗͇̼̤̩͈͓̗̣͋̋̐́̈́̎̽̎́̕̚͜͝į̶̨̧̺͔̼̻̠͉̤͋͌́͒͌̓̐̏̋͊̚͝͝ć̶̡̪͖̥̪̺̄̄̿̆́̃́̾́̕̕s̸̠̩̤̹̝̬̭͕̟̪̥̈́̀̆͘

Basically if it's not plain text in the language of your reader, it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: That looks surprisingly like [Vulcan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120057/51174) so I guess *no Vulcan?* ;-)

Comment: Unless we manage to last till the Federation :D

Comment: google prompted me to translate, with curious results https://i.stack.imgur.com/Favoh.gif

Comment: @uhoh Animated GIFs - another abomination :)

Comment: Once or twice I've included a url within an image description, is there any chance that would be bad (assuming the url itself wasn't)?

Comment: Do you understand the irony of using inaccessible spoiler markup in an answer about accessibility?

Comment: I'm still kinda curious about URLs appearing in the description. It's kinda convenient, but I always wonder if it could send somebody somewhere without them wanting to be sent somehow.

Comment: I wouldn't generally see it as bad but somewhat pointless unless the link bad value for someone who needed alt text @uhoh

Comment: @Tsundoku mildly but I was trying to give examples. I guess I could have done a screenshot, with unacceptable alt text instead.

Comment: I wonder if `[` and `]` need to be completely excluded as well, or are they okay in nested pairs? fyi I've linked to this page [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1824/12102).